# Python: iktFormatWarning

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, itk

I have the following problem. I imported itk and used it to filter a 3d array. Now in another part of my script, where i do some numpy array calculation stuff, i get an "**TypeError: itkFormatWarning() got an unexpected keyword argument 'line'"** Error and the script breaks up. Without importing itk, it show the warning "401: RuntimeWarning:divide by zero encountered in true_divide" but do not stop the script

```
sparseMatrix= (self.PlusMatrix+self.PufferMatrix*0.5)/self.MinusMatrix
```

PlusMatrix,MinusMatrix and Puffer Matrix are all 3d numpy arrays with the same dimensions. In some cases the division leads to np.nan and np.inf. I think here could be the problem. Can i somehow catch these error warnings?

Comment: Ok if i supress the numpy error, i also supress the itk warning, but how can i only supress the vtk warning?

Comment: You mean `itk`, not `vtk`? Provide more information, e.g. stack trace of the error or the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some implementation issue in the `itkFormatWarning()` provided by `itk`, that python points to when using ITK or a numpy array generated using ITK.

The following helped me, that is if you would like to ignore all the warnings.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

For the vtk warnings I just route it to a file.